# CH vs Not CH, What is the Consequence?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, foundations, continuum-hypothesis, cardinal-arithmetic

EDIT:  Altered (3) to say that $\beth_1$ can't be $\aleph_{\omega}$ or $\aleph_0$ but removed statement that it must be less than $\aleph_{\omega}$.

Let us assume ZFC.  We now consider 2 transfinite cardinals, $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0} = \beth_1$.  We know the following:

1. Given C, we know the cardinals are well-ordered and therefore comparable.  No partial order loophole.
2. $\aleph_1 \leq \beth_1$
3. $\beth_1 \neq \aleph_{\omega}$ and $\beth_1 \neq \aleph_0$.
4. $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of all well-orderings (up to order isomorphism) for countable sets.
5. $\beth_1$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

What happens when $\aleph_1 = \beth_1$ vs. not?  Are there just more ways to well-order the naturals that only exist when you postulate CH but can't be constructed with just ZFC?  Does having CH somehow make it so that there's fewer real numbers?  Assuming we define the reals using a 2nd order formulation, the latter doesn't seem possible.

These two sets seem fairly well-defined.  What exactly changes with CH vs. $\neg$CH?  I have no intuition here and it seems like either the smaller set gets bigger or the larger set gets smaller, but both seem silly.  The reals getting smaller seems sillier though.

Comment: 3. is wrong, $\beth_1\neq\aleph_\omega$, but nothing prevents it from being strictly bigger

Comment: Okay, I fixed (3) so that it no longer made a false claim.  However, that still leaves the main question intact.  The basic problem still remains.  What changes about the reals and/or the set of all order types on N when CH vs ~CH is assumed?  Something must be different in these 2 cases.